# Why my Vue Component do not return a value?

Tags: vue.js, kendo-ui, vue-component

I am new with Vue and I wanted to create a component wrapping the kendoComboBox and wanted to use the v-model on it, but it doesn't return an item selected. What is lacking on my code?

This is my Vue Component and the html.

```js
Vue.component('leave-type-2',
    {
        template: '<input v-bind:value="value" v-on:select="$emit("select", $event.target.dataItem)" />',
        props: ['value'],
        mounted: function() {
            var self = this;

            $(this.$el).kendoComboBox({
                dataSource: {
                    transport: {
                        read: {
                            url: "../LeaveTool/LeaveTypes",
                            dataType: "json"
                        }
                    }
                },
                dataTextField: "Description",
                dataValueField: "NumCode",
                filter: "contains",
                select: function(e) {
                    var dataItem = this.dataItem(e.item.index());
                    self.$emit('select', { "NumCode": dataItem.NumCode, "Description": dataItem.Description });
                },
                change: function() {

                }
            });
        }
    });
    
 const v = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: function () {
    return {
      leaveType: null
    }
  }
 });
```

```html
<div id="app">
    Leave Type Selected: {{ leaveType }}
    <leave-type-2 
      v-model="leaveType" 
      v-once style="width: 100%">
    </leave-type-2>
</div>
```

Comment: don't mix-use jquery and Vue, it is really not a good idea. then you may give a try after change `self.$emit('select', { "NumCode": dataItem.NumCode, "Description": dataItem.Description })` to `self.$emit('input', { "NumCode": dataItem.NumCode, "Description": dataItem.Description })`

Comment: thank you @Sphinx... I've placed self.$emit('input', { "NumCode": dataItem.NumCode, "Description": dataItem.Description }) under the event change of kendoComboBox and it returns now the value... I removed all under the select event... yes..it's true that it is not a good idea that is why I am wrapping this jquery so my Vue can communicate well... million thanks!

Comment: the exact answer is just to raise the correct event which is 'input'... 'select' event is wrong